# Boolean assigned value of 204 when false

Tags: c++

I have an object called `Symbol` which represents a variable. Symbol has the Boolean attribute `used` which is `initialized as false`. This condition is changed to true in the event that it is called upon to solve a function to show that it was used. For some reason when `Symbol` is unused and `used` is never changed to true it **returns the value 204 instead of false**.

Here is SymbolTable.h where I define a Symbol:

```
class SymbolTable  {
public:
    SymbolTable() {}
    void insert(string variable, double value);
    double lookUp(string variable) ;
    bool unusedVar() ;
private:
    struct Symbol  {
    Symbol(string variable, double value)
    {
        this->variable = variable;
        this->value = value;
        bool used = false;//This is my boolean flag
    }
    string variable;
    double value;
    bool used;
};
...
```

Whenever I look up a value from the SymbolTable to plug into a equation I set `used` to true:

```
double SymbolTable::lookUp(string variable)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        if (elements[i].variable == variable) {
        elements[i].used = true;//Right here it changes to true
        return elements[i].value;
    }
...
```

Later on when I try to detect if any are still false it wont work. And when I print the value of `used` it prints **204**!

```
bool SymbolTable::unusedVar() {// returns error if Var is not used
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "Variable: " << elements[i].variable << " was " << elements[i].used << std::endl;
    if ( !elements[i].used ) {
        std::cout << "Warning: A variable was not used" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

**Why could this be happening?**

Comment: You declared a local variable.  Use this->used instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you Hans. I'm very new to c++ so I'm having trouble coming from java. Do you think I should keep this question up or take it down?

Comment: This question was useful to me. Let's keep it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why could this be happening?

Two reasons:

1. `SymbolTable::Symbol::used` isn't initialized in the constructor `SymbolTable::Symbol(string, double)`, instead you're initializing the local variable.

   `bool used = false;//This is my boolean flag` - the bool in the beginning of the line makes it a declaration of a new local variable, hiding the member variable `used`; removing it will refer to the member variable `bool`. Alternatively, like Hans mentions in the comments, replacing that line with `this->used = false;` will fix it too.
2. You're not enabling the `std::boolalpha` flag and hence `std::cout` will print boolean values as integers only; thus the underlying integer value is getting printed; in this case, it's an uninitialized random value (204).

This should solve it:

```
struct Symbol {
    Symbol(string variable, double value) : variable(variable), value(value), used(false)
    {
    }
...

std::cout << "Variable: " << elements[i].variable << " was " << std::boolalpha << elements[i].used << std::endl;
```

In the constructor, instead of member-wise assignment, I've used [initialization lists, which is better](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists). In the printing code, I've used [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) for printing boolean as `true` or `false` instead of integers.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer! Thank you very much for going out of your way to explain the problem the required the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new to C++, from Java, I'd suggest you should pick up a beginner book from [The Definite C++ Book Guid and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/183120). I recommend [C++ Primer, 5th edition by Lippman](http://amzn.com/0321714113). Alternatively, [this article](http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html) may help for a quick preliminary introduction, although it isn't updated for C++11.

Comment: Thank you, my friend also recommended C++ Primer. I recently ordered [C Programming Language, 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131103628/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I understand its not C++ but I thought it would give me a good foundation before I tackle C++. After C C++ is next on my hit list.

Comment: Although C Programming Language is a great book, it's only if you want to learn C. If your ultimate aim is to learn C++, then you needn't learn C. In a few areas, you've to unlearn a few things in C to write idiomatic C++ code; but I guess it depends on each person's learning style: some learn it bottom up, while others top-down. This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/598552/183120) and [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dont-learn-c-first.html) will help you decide.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to learn C and C++. I'm already pretty good at Java and C#. I'm extremely dependent on OOP and I'm really excited about learning a strictly imperative language. Plus I've read learning C teaches you a lot about how the computer works.

Comment: Oh then you can learn C as a procedural language and move on to C++ as a [multi-paradigm language](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#multiparadigm); you can do imperative, procedural, object-oriented, generic programming styles. Both're great languages in their own right. Happy learning :)