# C# or C++? That is a question

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which language to learn: C, C# or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527700/which-language-to-learn-c-c-or-c)

What lang. do you suggest to learn?
I'm a beginner in programming and i have
some experiences with VB.
So C# or C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you had experience with VB, I think .NET would be good to start with. C# is one of the programming languages from MS .NET framework. But once you have deeper knowledge of programming, you may also want to look into how C, C++ works.

Answer (score 0):

C# will be easier for you to learn since it's managed just like vb but it's always good to know c++, there may be some concepts about memory management which may be confusing at first since you are coming from a managed language but once you understand them the rest will be easier i would go for c++, and then c#

Answer (score 0):

Since you note that you are a beginner, it would be wise to look at all languages available  for desktop and the web before trudging down a new path. There are way too many options available to only choose between C# and C++

This page might be useful, it attempts to list the languages by popularity: http://langpop.com/ .
I'm providing a different point of view because you aren't stating why you are choosing a new language.

Comment: Your kindly comments are appreciated, actually I'm a mechanical engineer, i need programming to solve my numerical problems in Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD).

Comment: If the thread: "Which language to learn: C, C# or C++?" doesn't answer your question, you might try re-asking your question including your intended purpose (ie CFD). You could also consider whether you need to visualize the data or just compute it. That might keep it from getting [closed]